# facing issue with python while connecting to teradata

Tags: python, teradata, apple-m1, teradatasql

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GA20081466/Desktop/LH_Imeitool/scripts/replication.py", line 93, in <module>
    with teradatasql.connect(host="xxxx", user="xxxx",
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/teradatasql/__init__.py", line 138, in __init__
    goside = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(sLibPathName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/teradatasql.dylib' (no such file)
```

Comment: Seems you're running an M1-Mac and there's no dylib for this architecture.

Comment: The Teradata JDBC driver is independent of hardware architecture, but otherwise Teradata utilities / drivers do not support M1 (yet?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The dylib included with the Teradata SQL Driver for Python is for Intel architecture.

At the present time, you need to use Rosetta. We plan to support M1 in the future.